# creating flask virtual environmnent in project folder

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a `flask` application for my web project

I know I need to install `flask` virtual environment in the project folder. 
I have `flask` already installed on my system. But whenever I try to create the virtual environment in `git` `bash` using the code below:

```
PATH=$PATH:C:/Users/ANUTUYI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe

python -m venv env
```

I get the following error

```
bash: python: command not found
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with Flask

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) if you're using VS Code.

Comment: Also, you don't put a file in `PATH`, you put a *directory* where the file is.

Comment: Also note that the Python extension for VS Code does not support git-bash. If you want to use Linux on Windows we do support WSL.

Comment: I need to create a virtual environment where I can run the flask application. So possibly people who run flask project could help with how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't set up the flask environment from VScode. So I went to the cmd prompt instead.

1. Went to my project folder titled "first" from the cmd prompt

```
C:\Users\ANUTUYI\Documents\Webprogramming\flask_app>cd first
```

2. typed the command `py -m venv env` to create the virtual environment in the project folder

```
C:\Users\ANUTUYI\Documents\Webprogramming\flask_app\first>py -m venv env
```

3. activated the environment by `env\Scripts\activate`. The `(env)` on the second line indicates we are now in the virtual environment.

```
C:\Users\ANUTUYI\Documents\Webprogramming\flask_app\first>env\Scripts\activate

(env) C:\Users\ANUTUYI\Documents\Webprogramming\flask_app\first>
```

4. then I was able to install flask into the virtual environment using `pip install flask`

```
(env) C:\Users\ANUTUYI\Documents\Webprogramming\flask_app\first>pip install flask
```